# key navigation with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm aware there are a lot of questions regarding navigation using keyboard events. However, as I want to understand everything and not just copy-paste stuff I couldn't find any good explanation or tutorial about the subject.

This is what I got so far and it's working for the left and right arrows. But if someone could point me in the right direction how to make it work for the up and down arrows as well, I would be very happy! And maybe it's not the most beautiful way to solve it, but for start I just want to understand the basic!

```
<a class="link" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Link 2</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Link 3</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Link 4</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Link 5</a>
<br />
<a class="link" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Link 2</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Link 3</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Link 4</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Link 5</a>



if (e.which == 39) {      
        $("a:focus").next().focus();

    }
    if (e.which == 37) {      
        $("a:focus").prev().focus();

    }
```

Comment: Probably you are looking for the different key codes. for up/down it's 38 and 40. for more info check it out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Comment: I know the keycodes, I know how to alert something on key up, the problem is I don't know how to for example move between divs using key up or down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a example spliting the links into two divs:

```
<div id="menu1">
    <a class="link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Link 5</a>
</div>
<div id="menu2">
    <a class="link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Link 5</a>
</div>
```

And attached the event:

```
$("a.link").on('keyup', function(e) {
    var current = $('a:focus');
    if (e.which == 39) {
        current.next().focus();
    }
    else if (e.which == 37) {      
        current.prev().focus();
    }
    // move to first link on previous div
    else if (e.which == 38) {
        current.parent().prev().find('a:first').focus();
    }
    // move to first link on next div
    else if (e.which == 40) {
        current.parent().next().find('a:first').focus();
    }
});

$("a.link:first").focus();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rogeriolino/g6s22676/

**EDIT**

Keeping the same index

```
// move to first link on previous div
else if (e.which == 38) {
    var index = current.index() + 1;
    current.parent().prev().find('a:nth-child(' + index + ')').focus();
}
// move to first link on next div
else if (e.which == 40) {
    var index = current.index() + 1;
    current.parent().next().find('a:nth-child(' + index + ')').focus();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rogeriolino/g6s22676/4/

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle, but the thing I want to achieve is to move the cursor up and down based on the current position. Exactly like left and right (prev, next) but for up and down.

Comment: Instead of use :first you can use ng-child passing the current index. Look: http://jsfiddle.net/rogeriolino/g6s22676/4/

Comment: Ah, thank you! I tried the nth-child but didn't get it right! Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to jump from row to row.

Try using the `:nth-child()` selector in jQuery, [info here](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), so you can select whatever element you want (in this case the one above).

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy working with this module when working with key bindings, it makes it a lot less complicated and the code is more readable / maintainable.

https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster